# An error occurs on the process monitor of the windows11 vm:Unable to load Process Monitor device driver

Tags: windows-11, macbook-pro

I installed windows11 virtual machine on m1 MacBook pro, then i installed Process Monitor on win11, but each time I run Process Monitor, it shows "Unable to load Process Monitor device driver". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Process monitor works fine on my Windows VM and Host. What Virtual App?  Is the Mac an ARM machine?

Comment: VMWare Fusion, and yes, it's ARM MAC.

Comment: May be that ARM is not allowing Process Monitor to run. Maybe try Parallels for ARM

Comment: Oh～OK, thank you!